# Can not complete drawline on JButton

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jbutton

So I am making a simple tic tac toe game and ran into a problem at the last minute

I am trying to draw a line at the win location but on the final win location(index), the line gets hidden behind the `JButton` not entirly sure why it is doing this.

I know alot of people say do not use `getGraphics()`, and I am wondering if that is the source of my issues they say to override the `paintComponent` method but that is not working for me either

I have attached a pic of what the result is looking like and code snips of how I am trying to perform these actions

PS I am using a `JFrame`, if any more code is needed I will be glad to show it

[image]

```
if(win[i] == 264){ // if one of the the combinations equal 'X','X','X' which equals 264, then there is a winner 
            System.out.println("X is the winner!!!");   
            System.out.println("Game Over!");
            number = i;
            draw(); }// call draw method 

 private void draw(){   // drawing a line at winning location 


Graphics2D  g1 = (Graphics2D) GUI.getFrame().getGraphics(); // declaring graphics on our Jframe 
    Stroke stroke3 = new BasicStroke(12f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER); // make our strokes cap off round 

    if(number == 0){ // statements will determine the win location, so at win0, XXX, 
        g1.setStroke(stroke3); // we will add stroke to our line 
        g1.drawLine(0,104,500,104); // draw the line starting at the 0,104 and end it at coordinates 500,104 
    }
```

here is a more runnable code, it is alot though

```
    import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class tic implements Runnable {
    final static int row = 3; // our rows 
    final static int col = 3; // our col 
    final static int sizeOfBoard = row * col; 
    // the size of our board is not going to change so we make it final
    static JButton[] clickButton;
    char[] templateOfBoard; // our board, TicTacToe field, static
    char userTurn; // users turn , only one letter, tracks whether it is a X or O 
    int count; // keeps track of user moves
    static JFrame frame; // our JFrame
    int number;


    public tic(JFrame frame) {

        tic.frame = new JFrame("TicTacToe GAME");  
        clickButton = new JButton[9];
        count = 0; // number of turns starts at 0;
        number = 0;

        setUserTurn('X'); // first turn will always be X
        setTemplateOfBoard(new char[sizeOfBoard]); // size of the board we are going to make it 


        try{
            for(int spaces=0; spaces<sizeOfBoard; spaces++){ // size of Board is in the GUI class

                getTemplateOfBoard()[spaces] = ' '; // the board is being created, looping through all rows and col

                //every index of the board not has a char value equal to a space 

                //determine if everything came out correctly 
                //should equal of a total of 9
                // 3x3
            }
            System.out.println("Board template created"); // means the board now has all spaces 
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not initalize the board to empty char");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new tic(frame)); // run 
        }
        catch(Exception e){ // wanted to test to ensure that Runnable could be invoked 
            System.out.println("Could not excute Runnable application");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()  {

        setup(); // going to run out setup method, what our game is made out of 
    } 

    public void setup() {
        // setting up the Board 
        // board is composed of JButton 
        // and a 3x3 frame 


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // when the user closes the window JFrame  will exit 

        //going to design the board now 
        //the dimensations of the board = sizeOfBoard

        getFrame().setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col)); // this is the outline rows * col 
        // sizes out row * col based on what we define those numbers as
        //i.e 3x3

        getFrame().setBounds(0,0,500,500); // location at 0,0, size 500 x 500 
        Border border = new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 2); // color of JButton border 

        System.out.println("Your board game is being created!");

        try{
            getFrame().setVisible(true); // shows the board, 
            // this is going to display everything to the screen 
            System.out.println("Board is now visable");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Board was not displayed");
        }

        // 9 different buttons, for every index there will be a button 
        for(int i =0; i<sizeOfBoard;i++){ // going to fill the board with clickableButtons by looping through every index and placing a button there 
            final int move = i;

            clickButton[i] = new JButton(); // at a certain index there is a new button 
            clickButton[i].setSize(250,250); // size of each button 
            clickButton[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE); // color of the JButton 

            getFrame().add(clickButton[i]); // we are going to add the actual the button at that index on the frame 

            clickButton[i].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 70)); // size of the text 
            clickButton[i].setBorder(border); // adding border 

            clickButton[i].getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() { //going to overRide what happens when we rollover and press a Butotn 

                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    ButtonModel button = (ButtonModel) e.getSource(); // manages the state of the button, i.e lets me control what happens to the button 

                    if(clickButton[move] != null){ // if we do not include this argument 
                        // the buttons are not made yet on the new game, meaning clickButton[i] = null
                        //so boolean(!button.isRollover()) will return true, since on the new game you can not have your mouse hovered over 
                        // but when it returns true, it will return a null value, giving a null pointer exception 
                        // so best thing to do, is to only run these cases below when the buttons are not null

                        if (button.isRollover()) { // when the mouse hovers over the index 
                            clickButton[move].setBackground(Color.BLACK); // color will equal black 
                        }
                        else if(!button.isRollover()){ // when the button is not hovered over
                            clickButton[move].setBackground(Color.WHITE); // color will be whte, just like our background 
                        }

                    }
                }
            });


            clickButton[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 

                //our click events, going to override to let it know what we want to happen
                //once we click on the button
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                    clickButton[move].setEnabled(false); //going to disable the button after it is clicked 
                    //ORDER: button gets clicked first, then the test is added
                    mouseListener(e, move); // our mouseListenerEvent in game class 

                    //
                } 
            });
        }           
    }


    public static void playAgain() {

        try{
            System.out.println("NEW GAME");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new tic(frame));  // run the run(class) again 
        }
        catch(Exception e){ // wanted to test to ensure that Runnable could be invoked 
            System.out.println("Could not excute Runnable application");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public tic userMove(int moveMade){

        getTemplateOfBoard()[moveMade] = getUserTurn();
        // index of the board, or in simpler terms, where the user
        // inserts there turn i.e X or O, 0-8
        //System.out.println(userMove);

        //boolean statement to determine the turns 
        // So user X starts first
        //if the turn is X, the nextTurn is now O,

        if(getUserTurn() == 'X'){
            setUserTurn('O');   
        }
        else {
            setUserTurn('X');
        }

        count++; 

        return this; // going to return the userTurn
        // issue actually entering the userTurn is not giving right value, but using 'this' does 
    }


    // for some odd reason the toString is causing some issues, keep getting @hash code
    //saw online to override it like this 
    // will make the board out of emepty strings 
    // going to return a string representation of an object 
    public String toString(){
        return new String(getTemplateOfBoard());
    }

    public void mouseListener(ActionEvent e, int moveMade){ 
        // mouse click events 
        // what happens after a button is clicked 

        if(getTemplateOfBoard()[moveMade] == ' '){ // the user can only space a click, so an letter on the field if it is empty 
            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText(Character.toString(getUserTurn())); // when the button is clicked, we want an X placed there 
            if (getUserTurn() == 'X'){
                UIManager.getDefaults().put("Button.disabledText",Color.RED); // when the but gets disabled the test will turn red      
            }
            else{
                UIManager.getDefaults().put("Button.disabledText",Color.BLUE);
            }
            //calling the method userTurn to determine who goes next
            //problem is that is expects a String
            //going to override the toString method 

            userMove(moveMade); // calling userMove in moveMade, moveMade is the index at which the user put either an X or a O
            winner(); // we want to check each time to ensure there was/was not a winner 

        } 

    }


    public tic winner() { // determines who is the winner


        //list below defines all the possible win combinations 
        // the index of where a X or O can be place
        // placed the locations to a int value 
        int win1 = templateOfBoard[0] + templateOfBoard[1] + templateOfBoard[2];    
        int win2 = templateOfBoard[3] + templateOfBoard[4] + templateOfBoard[5];
        int win3 = templateOfBoard[6] + templateOfBoard[7] + templateOfBoard[8];
        int win4 = templateOfBoard[0] + templateOfBoard[3] + templateOfBoard[6];
        int win5 = templateOfBoard[1] + templateOfBoard[4] + templateOfBoard[7];
        int win6 = templateOfBoard[2] + templateOfBoard[5] + templateOfBoard[8];
        int win7 = templateOfBoard[0] + templateOfBoard[4] + templateOfBoard[8];
        int win8 = templateOfBoard[2] + templateOfBoard[4] + templateOfBoard[6];

        int[] win = new int[]{win1,win2,win3,win4,win5,win6,win7,win8}; 
        // making a array to go through all the possibile wins 
        //possible total of wins is 8


        for(int i = 0;i<win.length;i++){     
            // looping through the win possibilities 


            if(win[i] == 264){ // if one of the the combinations equal 'X','X','X' which equals 264, then there is a winner 
                System.out.println("X is the winner!!!");   
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
                number = i;
                draw(); // call draw method 



                return this; // if statement is true, it will return this(gameOver)
            }
            else if(win[i] == 237 ){ // if one of the the combinations equal 'O','O','O' which equals 234, then there is a winner 
                System.out.println("O is the winner!!!");
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
                number = i;
                //draw(); // call draw method 




                return this;

            }

            if (count == 9) {
                // if none of the statements above are true, it automatically comes done to here
                //so if there is nine moves and no win, it is a draw 


            } 

        }

        return this; 
        // going to return this method ;
    } 

    private void draw(){    // drawing a line at winning location 


        Graphics2D  g1 = (Graphics2D) getFrame().getGraphics(); // declaring graphics on our Jframe 
        Stroke stroke3 = new BasicStroke(12f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER); // make our strokes cap off round 

        if(number == 0){ // statements will determine the win location, so at win0, XXX, 
            g1.setStroke(stroke3); // we will add stroke to our line 
            g1.drawLine(0,104,500,104); // draw the line starting at the 0,104 and end it at coordinates 500,104 
        }
        else if(number == 1){
            g1.setStroke(stroke3);
            g1.drawLine(0,257,500,257);
        }
        else if(number == 2){
            g1.setStroke(stroke3);
            g1.drawLine(0,411,500,411); 
        }
        else if(number == 3){
            g1.setStroke(stroke3);
            g1.drawLine(88,0,88,500);   
        }
        else if(number == 4){
            g1.setStroke(stroke3);
            g1.drawLine(250,0,250,500);
        }
        else if(number == 5){
            g1.setStroke(stroke3);
            g1.drawLine(411,0,411,500);
        }
        else if(number == 6){
            g1.setStroke(stroke3);
            g1.drawLine(-22,0,500,500);

        }
        else if(number == 7){
            g1.setStroke(stroke3);
            g1.drawLine(520,0,0,500);
        }
    }

    // want to be able to access the private variables 
    //so we will make getter and setter methods for the ones that we need
    public char getUserTurn() { // getter method for userTurn
        return userTurn;
    }

    public void setUserTurn(char userTurn) { // setter method 
        this.userTurn = userTurn;
    }

    public char[] getTemplateOfBoard() { //getter method 
        return templateOfBoard;
    }

    public void setTemplateOfBoard(char[] templateOfBoard) { // setter method 
        this.templateOfBoard = templateOfBoard;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, DON'T SHOUT!

Comment: Required reading: http://bash.org/?835030 and http://bash.org/?105199

Comment: PROBLEM WITH KEYBOARD, I WILL SWITCH TO ANOTHER COMPUTER

Comment: `Graphics2D  g1 = (Graphics2D) GUI.getFrame().getGraphics();`  That is ***not*** how to do custom painting is Swing!  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for details.

Comment: *"do not use getGraphics(), and I am wondering if that is the source of my issues"* - It's a good bet; *"they say to override the paintComponent method but that is not working for me either"* - Then you have a different issue

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson how would I make the changes to make it work into my code ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson for you to recreate the this solution, I would have to provide you the my entire source code, or it will not work, I can provide anybody with my git if that helps

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: here is the link to my source code, if anybody wants to run ithttps://github.com/michelc1/Tic-Tac-Toe/tree/master/src@MadProgrammer @AndrewThompson

Comment: I'm not surfing off for the entire source code.  If you cannot prepare an MCVE, I'll help other people who can.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Alright just posted above a runnable code,hope this helps, thanks so much for your assistance

Answer (score 2):

Painting over the top of components can be troublesome, you can't override the `paintComponent` method of the container which contains the components, because this paints in the background, you can't override the `paint` method of the container, as child components can be painted without the parent container been notified...

You could add a transparent component over the whole lot, but this just introduces more complexity, especially when a component already already exists ...

[image: Connect the dots]

```
public class ConnectTheDots {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConnectTheDots();
    }

    public ConnectTheDots() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                PaintPane pp = new PaintPane();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setGlassPane(pp);
                pp.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new DotsPane(pp));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        private List<JButton[]> connections;
        private JButton lastSelected;

        public PaintPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            connections = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (lastSelected != null) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                int x = lastSelected.getX() + ((lastSelected.getWidth() - 8) / 2);
                int y = lastSelected.getY() + ((lastSelected.getHeight() - 8) / 2);
                g2d.fillOval(x, y, 8, 8);
            }
            for (JButton[] group : connections) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                Point startPoint = group[0].getLocation();
                Point endPoint = group[1].getLocation();
                startPoint.x += (group[0].getWidth() / 2);
                startPoint.y += (group[1].getHeight()/ 2);
                endPoint.x += (group[0].getWidth() / 2);
                endPoint.y += (group[1].getHeight()/ 2);
                g2d.draw(new Line2D.Float(startPoint, endPoint));
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void buttonClicked(JButton btn) {
            if (lastSelected == null) {
                lastSelected = btn;
            } else {
                connections.add(new JButton[]{lastSelected, btn});
                lastSelected = null;
            }
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public class DotsPane extends JPanel {

        private PaintPane paintPane;

        public DotsPane(final PaintPane pp) {
            paintPane = pp;
            ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    paintPane.buttonClicked(btn);
                }
            };
            setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6));
            for (int index = 0; index < 6 * 6; index++) {
                JButton btn = new JButton(".");
                add(btn);
                btn.addActionListener(al);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details

Comment: So me painting over the components is the root to my problem?

Comment: The way you're painting over your components is your root problem ;)

Comment: I added a more complete code, maybe you can take a look and see what exactly I am doing wrong and maybe through me a hint?

Comment: Take your `draw` method, move it to a `paintComponent` method of another component, make that component transparent, make that component the glass pane of the frame, tell it when you want it to draw a line by changing it's state appropriately...

Comment: very complicaced code, but plus one