# How does java.awt.Graphics.drawLine work?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to look at the source code for the drawLine method, but I can't find it anywhere. I've learned that it is implemented natively by the jre, so that's why it's not defined in the Graphics class.

I want to know this because I'm trying to figure how to draw a line between two tiles in a 20x20 grid, and so I think looking at this class will help.

Comment: In most cases, it delegates to the native graphics API of the platform, typically using either DirectX or OpenGL based libraries. I'm not sure why you need to know how it's implemented, only that if you pass it four coordinates it does

Comment: Without (a lot) more detail, it's hard to know what to suggest, maybe something line [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467411/java-drawing-a-line-between-the-centre-of-components/28467636#28467636) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414017/can-not-complete-drawline-on-jbutton/27414334#27414334)

Comment: Have you tried looking at Oracle's docs? Do they have anything on this?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not looking to draw a line between the two tiles using the drawLine method. I want to change the colour of each tile between the two so it forms a line. Like how the drawLine method changes the pixels in between the two points to whatever colour.

Comment: @RegisteredUser No but I'll try that!

Comment: Great! Go ahead and report back what you see by editing your question

Comment: @RegisteredUser Coudn't find any source code from them. Just the documentation.

Comment: Try googling more. Also adding detail would help, as @MadProgrammer said. try googling `java.awt.graphics examples` or something like that.

Comment: Try googling ["line drawing algorithim"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=line+drawing+algorithm&oq=line+drawing+al&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5513j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8). What I might do is use a 2D array as a virtual representation of your title grid and calculate which cells would be intersected by a virtual line drawn between two cells, the translate that to your titles. The idea is to treat the 2D array as if they were pixels

Comment: @MadProgrammer awesome, exactly what I was looking for! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/37a05a11f281/src/share/classes/sun/java2d/loops/DrawLine.java

Should be the OpenJDK drawline method's source code...